# Cannot post in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to upload file using node.js , being new to it a tried to check if the file is being send to server.
html

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="img" method="POST" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
var express  = require("express");
var app=express();
var http=require("http").Server(app);


app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.end("hello")
});

app.get("/upload",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/form.html")
})
app.post("/img",function(req,res){
    if(req.files){
     console.log(req.files.file.name);
    }
    else{
        console.log("ee")
    }


});
http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("listening on 3000")
})
```

When i upload something , it throws error

> Cannot read files of undefined

Being new to back end i have no idea why its happening , why doesnt the server recieve the file?

Comment: what line throws this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `app.use()` a fileparser. For example, you could use [**`connect-busboy`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy). You can get more information about options and usage at above link; a simple setup would be somehting like this:

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
app.use(busboy());

app.post("/img",function(req,res){
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            // ...
        });
        req.busboy.on('field', function (key, value, keyTruncated, valueTruncated) {
            // ...
        });
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
        // etc ...
});
```

Comment: isnt there build in / native modile for fileparser , or do i have to use external modules for that? I am begginer , at first i would like to know it without using external modules

Comment: No, there isn't. Your only alternative is coding it by yourself. @J.dd

Comment: Im quite interessted in it. I know i will propably use some module , but where can i read about that - about stuff behind creating own fileparser? I fail to find anything

Comment: I think a good starting point would be reading the source code of an existing fileparser, like posted above. Then you'll also find the terminology to do google searches on parts of it

Comment: @J.dd There is a complete middleware for express for parsing uploaded files. Check my response below. :)

Comment: @J.dd Also, writing your own file parser can become a royal pain, and in the end you're just quite reinventing the wheel. And also you can have some hard to find/debug problems within your code. But on the bright side, you'll learn how to handle a multipart body in depth which is quite a good thing, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the above answer, you must use a body parser for multipart bodies, but the better solution is to use the express middleware [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) which lets you to use `req.files` just like in your OP.

Also, multer is built on top of busboy which is the fastest multipart body parser for node.js

With multer:

```
var express = require('express'),
    multer = require("multer"),
    app = express();

app.use(multer({
    dest: path.resolve(__root + path.sep + config.get("localFolders").rawImages),
    limits: {
         files: 2
    }
}));

// handle file upload
app.post("/img", function (req, res, next) {
    var image = req.files.image;
    // do something with image;
    console.log(image.name);
});
```

Have a look on the documentation for multer within the link provided above. Good luck. :)